# PostgreSQL view column naming

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to name a new column in my view... here is (part of) my code:

```
SELECT co_url_name, score_combined,(SELECT trunc(("productAndServices" + "futurePurchase" + shipping + "customerService" + returns + "lifetimeRating")/6, 2) AS resellerRating)
```

Basically it's just an average of a bunch of columns.

However, the column comes up named `?column?` instead and was wondering how I need to change my syntax to name the column `resellerRating` instead.

I tried `ALTER VIEW myview RENAME COLUMN "?column?" TO resellerRating;` and not surprisingly got an error.... can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your view definition to this:

```
SELECT 
    co_url_name, 
    score_combined,
    (SELECT trunc(("productAndServices" + "futurePurchase" + shipping + "customerService" + returns + "lifetimeRating")/6, 2)) AS resellerRating
```

If you want to post your whole query here, I can refactor it, but as it were, you need to put the alias outside the subquery.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but this answers my question perfectly. I'll accept your answer soon as I can! Thank you!